# android weird onCreate / onDestroy balance

Tags: android, singleton, android-activity, oncreate, android-lifecycle

is there a way to tell Android that I would like subsequent calls to startActivity() all resume the target activity rather than creating it over and over again ? Any workarounds ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs, try using [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) or [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) when creating your intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NameOfActivityClass.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: these flags seem to be what I amafter, but none of them work. Anything special that need to get into the manifest file ?

Comment: marked as answer. I was not overriding the onDestroy method, but onStop, and that is why I got confused. However, it is still srange that Android decides to destroy that activity (part of the current running task) while system load is almost 0.